# Is there any possible way to create a docker image without docker installed on my development machine?

Tags: docker, eclipse-plugin, ibm-cloud, dockerfile, docker-image

I have access to my company's Bluemix offering where I can upload a docker image.
I am trying to build a docker image without downloading docker.exe/msi. Trying to download docker plugin for eclipse(which doesn't work).Is there a way to create just a dockerfile and then create a docker image out of it (using only eclipse plugin) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a GitHub or BitBucket repository with a Dockerfile inside of it and create an automated build on Docker Hub, which would build it and make it available to you.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/

Comment: I dont have the docker CLI too inorder to pull the images from dockerhub ..